# Client side scripts through proxies

Tags: javascript, vpn, proxy, client-side

If you're trying to hide your IP address using VPN/proxies can a website using client side scripting record your real ip? If yes is there any alternative to blocking all scripts as that breaks majority of the websites out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally speaking as long as the client sided script has not been designed for malicious use (of tracking the true IP) it should be forced to use the proxy as well. What I mean is that as long as the script itself is not a form of exploit/hack designed to bypass this.

In the case of VPNs, all traffic is routed through the VPN. None of it can go from outside it. Same for proxies, depending on whether the proxy is a system wide one or a browser only one.

However, if you're sure your configurations are correct then you need not worry about your IP getting revealed. On a related note, companies like Google have managed to obtain other information that could potentially identify you and your exact location even with people using VPNs. If you're wanting to hide your IP, then yes this does that, but it may not suffice for hiding your identity. :)

Answer (score 5):

As Wilson Wong says, all browser requests should be routed via the proxy *depending on [how the browser is configured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_auto-config)* / whether there is any transparent proxying implemented on the default route.

It is possible to determine the IP address [by other means](http://reglos.de/myaddress/MyAddress.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using proxy or VPN visit the webpage, I believe any ajax call will use the same proxy/VPN connection, so the server still seeing your proxy's IP unless your request will dynamically switch between proxy & your real IP depends on the domain.